# Hide the Application in Application Management in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

My app is working on background.

I want to hide my Application in Blackberry Application Management.

option ->  Device -> Appliation Management

Is it possible ?

How I can achieve this ?

Comment: For distribution of an app on a locked-down phone in your enterprise?

Comment: Yes. @MichaelPetrotta its in running on background only.

Comment: I don't think so it is possible. As because, in Application Management, every application should be displayed, it may be foreground, Background or Library App. If it is really possible, want to know how?

Comment: Can you explain why you need this?

Comment: Are you referring to or requesting for background services where you wish to have your app in the background and able to see within a panel the list of applications running in the background?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible for BlackBerry 10 currently or in the future.  The end user is required to have control of all third-party applications running on the device at all times.  An application running in the background needs to be visible and accessible from within an application panel.